# Estoy usando NodeJS para crear el backend de mi app de android en flutter y a la hora de usar el paquete socket_io_client no se me conecta el socket

Tags: android, nodejs, flutter, socket.io

Aquí mi código en flutter de mi socket service

OJO no me da error simplemente no me funciona el socket ni me notifica que el usuario esta conectado ni el backend detecta que hay un usuario conectado, sin embargo me conecto con el navegador al servidor y si detecta que hay un usuario conectado. Si me funcionan las peticiones al servidor

Ya probe también con el navegador del emulador de android entrar en esta dirección http://10.0.2.2:3000 y si se me conecta bien al socket

```
import 'package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart' as IO;

enum ServerStatus { Online, Offline, Connecting }

class SocketService with ChangeNotifier {
  ServerStatus _serverStatus = ServerStatus.Connecting;
  late IO.Socket _socket;

  ServerStatus get serverStatus => _serverStatus;

  IO.Socket get socket => _socket;
  Function get emit => _socket.emit;

  void connect() { // metodo para conectar el socket
    // Dart client
    _socket = IO.io(
        'http://10.0.2.2:3000',
        IO.OptionBuilder()
            .setTransports(['websocket'])
            .enableForceNew()
            .enableAutoConnect()
            .build());
   

    _socket.onConnect((_) {  // cuando se conecta el socket
      _serverStatus = ServerStatus.Online; 
      print('Online');
      notifyListeners();// Notifico los cambios con provider
    });

    _socket.onDisconnect((_) {
      _serverStatus = ServerStatus.Offline;
      print('Offline');
      notifyListeners();
    });
    print(_socket.connected);
  }

  void disconnect() { //metodo para desconectar el socket
    _socket.disconnect();
  }
}
```

Depuré para ver si entra al método onConnect() pero nunca entra

```
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:chat/services/socket_service.dart';

//En este metodo es donde conecto el socket

  Future checkLoginState(BuildContext context) async {
    final authService = Provider.of<AuthService>(context, listen: false);
    final socketService = Provider.of<SocketService>(context); //Utilizo provider para refrescar la pantalla

    final authenticating = await authService.isLoggedIn();

    if (authenticating) {
      socketService.connect(); // Aquí conecto el socket
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        PageRouteBuilder(
          pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => const UsersPage(),
          transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 0),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        PageRouteBuilder(
          pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => const LoginPage(),
          transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 0),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "localhost" ,  revisa en el navegador de tu dispositivo(emulador o fisico) si es que puedes llegar a esa url , creo que si usas el emulador de android, la url de localhost es 10.0.2.2

Comment: La URL que tengo es esa que usted dice fue que me equivoqué al escribirlo en la pregunta, pero gracias de todas formas

Comment: revisaste si desde el navegador de tu celular/emulador puedes llegar a esa url?

Comment: Si, mi aplicación es de chat y a la hora de autenticarme si entra de lo más bien y funcionan bien las peticiones el problema es el socket que  no se por qué no se me quiere conectar

Comment: en que momento conectas al socket, puedes agregar ese código ? depuraste para ver si entra al método?

Comment: Al método onConnect nunca entra

Comment: probaste la conexión al socket en un proyecto separado? solo para confirmar que no sea algun problema de la gestión de estado en tu proyecto actual

Comment: Probe en otro proyecto separado y no funciona el socket tampoco

Comment: que versión estás usando? intenta la beta 2.0.0-beta.4-nullsafety.0    https://github.com/rikulo/socket.io-client-dart/issues/269#issuecomment-1112523741

Comment: Muchísimas gracias era eso mismo, era la versión, llevaba tres días en eso y no daba con el problema

Comment: ¿Como puedo marcar que la pregunta ya esta respondida?

Comment: agregaré una respuesta para que marques

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer hay un error con las versiones "estables" del package `socket_io_client`, no sucede nada al conectar.

Ya fue reportado en el mismo repositorio y sugieren usar la versión beta.

https://github.com/rikulo/socket.io-client-dart/issues/269#issuecomment-1112523741

La versión beta está como pre-release, pero puede ser usada sin problemas.

https://pub.dev/packages/socket_io_client/versions/2.0.0-beta.4-nullsafety.0

```yaml
socket_io_client: ^2.0.0-beta.4-nullsafety.0
```

Con esto se corregiría el problema de conexión.